# How to get data to auto populate from one table to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I’ve tried searching for help on this but everything I find is way more complicated than what I need and I just get lost following along. This is what I’m looking for:

If table titled “Applicants” on worksheet “Applicants” has a “Yes” in column I (Column I is titled “Offer” with the header in I1), then I want the name of the applicant in Column A (Titled “Name”) to Populate to Table “Hired” on worksheet “Hired” into Column A (titled “Name”).

Data range for table “Applicants” is A1:K69 with A1-K1 being the column headers.

Table “Hired” headers are A1-G1 with the first input for Column A being A2. Columns B-G is all manual entry.

I’ve tried to do this myself with other explanations/videos but simply cannot translate the examples to my own table. Also, I want to actually learn how this is done and am not looking for a copy and paste formula. So if someone is able to explain exactly what is happening and what each part of the formula is doing that would be fantastic!

Comment: You can use either INDEX & MATCH combination or even VLOOKUP ,,, ☺

Comment: Could you please share us with a simple sample? Generally, we could use lookup, index function to search values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-VBA method for achieving what you need. I would recommend that future questions be reduced to the bare minimum to avoid TLDR reactions. Also, sample data and visual of desired results are also recommended.

Cell E2 formula:

```
    =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$6,SMALL(IF("Yes"=$B$2:$B$6,ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

With your cursor in the formula, press CTRL+ALT+ENTER to make this an Array formula to get the curly brackets. It's important, otherwise this will not work as desired. Then drag your formula down well beyond how far you need it. An error handler has been wrapped around this formula to simply display a "blank" if no more matches are found.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was actually able to get it to work using the following formula:

=FILTER(INDEX(Applicants,SEQUENCE(ROWS(Applicants)),{1,13,12,11}),Applicants[Offer]="Yes")

Is there really a difference between these two formulas? I did notice though that when trying to have to data populate into a blank table I would receive a #spill! error and the data would not populate until I converted the table back to a data range.